# gpg2 can't decrypt password store

Tags: gnupg

I've migrated my home directory to a new machine, and now pass wont decrypt my passwords.  I think I've narrowed the issue down to gpg2.
If I run the command

```
gpg --decrypt < ~/.password-store/foo
```

it prompts me for my passphrase (in the CLI) and decrypts the file.
However,

```
gpg2 --decrypt < ~/.password-store/foo
```

prompts me for my passphrase in pinentry-gtk, but then it outputs

```
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID D86A742B, created 2015-06-15
  "Mark Johnson <mark@barrenfrozenwasteland.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Invalid IPC response
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I definitely have the secret key installed:

```
$ gpg2 --list-secret-keys 
/home/mark/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-----------------------------
sec   rsa2048/D6E3E9B8 2015-06-15 [SC]
uid         [ultimate] Mark Johnson <mark@barrenfrozenwasteland.com>
ssb   rsa2048/D86A742B 2015-06-15 [E]
```

and its definitely tells me its decrypting that key in pinentry-gtk

Answer (score 0):

I'm running KDE plasma, and I also have pinentry-qt installed.  Uninstalling pinentry-gtk made it use pinentry-qt instead, and it worked.